# binding <input type="radio"> with Model field?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

In a view I have two  `<input type="radio">`, combine they make a radio group.

I want to bind them with a field of Model, in a way if value is true it should bind first radio button if false it should bind the other.

Please guide how it can be achived. I tried below code but it always checked the second radio no matter what value model has.

```
<div class="radiobuttons">
  <input type="radio" name="LenderType" checked="@Model.Filter_Value" id="rbtnAllLenders" class="cb">
  <input type="radio" id="rbtnMajorLendersOnly" checked="!@Model.Filter_Value" name="LenderType" class="cb">
</div>
```

Comment: Show you model (what is the property you want to bind to and what are the possible values)

Answer (score 1):

The input typed as radio needs to have a value set. If the radio is checked, then the value is what is sent for the name in the model.

view model

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
 public int MyRadioValue { get; set; }
}
```

input element

```
<input type="radio" value=1 name="MyRadioValue" />
<input type="radio" value=2 name="MyRadioValue" />
<input type="radio" value=3 name="MyRadioValue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You manual code is adding the `selected` attribute to both radio buttons. All the following are equivalent:

```
<input type="radio" ... checked />
<input type="radio" ... checked="selected" />
<input type="radio" ... checked="true" />
<input type="radio" ... checked="false" />
```

Note the last 2 are invalid values for the `checked` attribute, but still check the radio button. Since you have a group name, and only one button can be visually checked, the last one rendered is selected. [Refer W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#radio-button-state-(type=radio)).

Use html helpers to bind to your model. If the model contains property `string LenderType` then

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LenderType, "All lenders", new { id = "All"})<label for="All">All lenders</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LenderType, "Major lenders", new { id = "Major"})<label for="Major">Major lenders</label>
```

If the value of `LenderType` is "All lenders" the first option will be selected. If the value is "Major lenders", then the second option will be selected

Answer (score 0):

Create Html Helper ....

```
 public static HtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems, RadioButtonListLayout layout)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in selectListItems)
            {
                var itemId = string.Format(
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "{0}_{1}",
                    helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)),
                    item.Value);

                var itemHtml = string.Format(
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "{0} <label for=\"{1}\">{2}</label>",
                    helper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = itemId }),
                    itemId,
                    item.Text);

                if (layout == RadioButtonListLayout.Horizontal)
                {
                    sb.Append("<span class=\"radiobuttonlist-horizontal\">");
                    sb.Append(itemHtml);
                    sb.AppendLine("</span>");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append("<div class=\"radiobuttonlist-vertical\">");
                    sb.Append(itemHtml);
                    sb.AppendLine("</div>");
                }
            }

            return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
        }
```

Use it ...

```
@Html.RadioButtonListFor(x=>x.Id,Model.ListItem,RadioButtonListLayout.Horizontal)
```